# PHP Headers from Raw Post Stream

Tags: php, api, shopify

I am trying to access the X-Shopify-* headers from this raw post request in php:

http://requestb.in/txqnuftx?inspect

I don't have the http and apache extensions installed.

I've tried `headers_list()` but they are not listed.

What else can I try? Could it be something I need to enable in php.ini or .htaccess?

My host is Go Daddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [getallheaders()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php) or [http_get_request_headers()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-headers.php) only available from the extensions you don't currently have installed.

It does appear that some headers are automatically added to the `$_SERVER` variable with "HTTP_" in front of them, so I would dump that array and check there first.  You'll find underscores instead of hyphens.  On one of my setups a proxy server's injected "X-" header is showing up in there.

Comment: It is available in $_SERVER `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_SHOPIFY_SHOP_DOMAIN']`